# laravel php artisan not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a project with Laravel. But today suddenly php artisan didn't work anymore. It gives me an error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debu\Exception\FatalErrorException] syntax error,
>   unexpected end of file

Already googled a lot but can't realy find an answer. Today I've removed the "public" from my url perhaps it has something to do with that I changed my index.php to this:

```
require __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

And everything that was in the public folder I moved to the root.

Comment: Try deleting your `vendor` directory and reinstalling with `composer install`.

Comment: You have a file (that artisan loads) that is missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: Is that the only error you get? In that case, take a look in you php error log and let us know what you find.

Comment: Yes, I receive this error, for example if I want to make a model.

Comment: Reinstalled vendor and not it works !